# Installing the filter driver programmatically?

Tags: windows, networking, driver, device-driver, ndis

I am trying to write C++ code programmatically installing NDIS 6.0 lightweight filter driver. After reviewing WinDDK, online examples and MSDN documentation I ended up with the code sample below.

```
**************
hr = InstallSpecifiedComponent(
        ModuleFileName,
        L"MS_NdisLwf",
        &GUID_DEVCLASS_NETSERVICE
        );
**************

hr = HrInstallNetComponent( 
        pnc,
        lpszPnpID,
        pguidClass,
        lpszInfFile     
         );
**************
   if ( !SetupCopyOEMInfW(lpszInfFullPath,
                       DirWithDrive,  // Other files are in the same dir.as primary INF
                           SPOST_PATH,    // SPOST_NONE, //First param is path to INF
                           0,             // Default copy style
                           NULL,// Name of the INF after it's copied to %windir%\inf
                           0,            // Max buf. size for the above
                           NULL,          // Required size if non-null
                           NULL) // Optionally get the filename part of Inf name 
                                 after it is copied.
                        ) 
        {
            ---- 
        }

***************     
hr = HrInstallComponent( pnc,
                             lpszComponentId,
                             pguidClass );

***************

hr = pnc->QueryNetCfgClass ( pguidClass,
                         IID_INetCfgClassSetup,
                         (void**)&pncClassSetup );                           

if ( hr == S_OK ) {

wprintf(L"\n No Test\n");

hr = pncClassSetup->Install( szComponentId,
                             &OboToken,
                             0,
                             0,       // Upgrade from build number.
                             NULL,    // Answerfile name
                             NULL,    // Answerfile section name
                             &pncc ); // Reference after the component          
if ( S_OK == hr ) {  ... }                 // is installed.
```

The path using INetCfgClassSetup::Install does not work.

It is taking the default path in the Have Disk Browse Options

eg: my inf file path is C:\Users\Mani\Desktop\sagar\objchk_win7_x86\i386\netlwf.inf

but it is asking for the default path(1st entry) in have disk menu

d:\softwares\filter_driver

similar to the image ==> https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmyMX.png

It is always asking for the same sys file.

Is anything was missing ?

Comment: Can you also share out the INF?

Comment: Please check out the link

my inf is file is almost similar in nature
[INF_FILE](http://weppinhole.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/WifiCaptureService/netlwf.inf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is over a year old, and I hope that you have found the solution. For the sake of developers facing same problem, I posting this answer.

Start with ProtInstall project at ndis.com

http://www.ndis.com/ndis-general/ndisinstall/programinstall.htm

you might need to make some changes : include the header files, libraries; and some debugging.

Other than that, this project works and I have successfully installed and uninstalled ndislwf 6.0 sample project via this.